# Highlight specific area in a box in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

My problem can be easily illustrated by the first picture on this site:
http://bitmedia.dk/rentegning-af-kommunekort-til-faktaillustration/

I already have the overall map, but I want to make a box in print composer where the specific area of some municipalities are highlighted.

Best regards,
Kasper

Comment: What software are you using? QGIS?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that. Yes, QGIS.

Comment: Please provide an example/mockup of what you want to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by highlighted: Selected or styled or??
Do you want the same geometry, in two different maps, with different style for the same geometry? The style in your two maps from your link (first picture) is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret lies on the lock layers option in the map item properties.

First, you need to prepare the layer for your "overview" map in the map canvas. That is, a layer with the desired municipalities already filtered, and turn off all the other layer that you don't want to be seen in the overview map.

Open the print composer and add a new map, just like [Sorin Călinică](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23369/sorin-clinic) said, and adjust it to the size you want.

[image]

Now lock the layers of that map item.

[image]

Go back to map canvas, turn the original layers on (and probably the ones you use off). Know refreshing the print composer, you will see that your overview map will not be changed.

[image]

Note: Since you already have the overall\base map prepared, you can lock the base instead.  But chances are that you probably will change that map a lot more that the overview one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

[image]

For this, just add a new map over the first one, then you can highlight any portion of map you wish.

Comment: I should have been more specific. My bad. I want the box only to contain specific municipalities. So in the example from the question I don't want parts of a municipality. I want to select, say 10 municipalities, and then these are highlighted in the bo - not parts the surrounding municipalities.